# Remove duplicates the simplest way / explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

First I would like to remark that I (as a Newb) did search through several Q & A regarding duplicates in a table though unfortunately for me, I couldn't manipulate the code being used as answer.

My table is made out of a report being sorted in SQL Server 2008.

I would like to know how do I remove duplicate records and with an explanation.

```
"MyTable":

Column1   (PK-auto incremental table's record ID) 
Column2   (some TXT) 
Column3   (Some TXT)
Column4   (SmallDateTime)
Column5   is empty
```

Column5 will hold the value of `SUM(count of deleted duplicates including this survived row)`

The key to the solution in may case is if `[column2 and column3]` have multiple records with same content (hence Duplicates) only they don't always share the same date (`column4`).

From this:

```
col1  col2   col3  col4         col5
----  -----  ----  -----------  ----
1     [abc]  [4]   [10/1/2012]  null
2     [abc]  [1]   [12/1/2012]  null
3     [ghi]  [6]   [4/1/2012]   null
4     [def]  [5]   [8/1/2012]   null
5     [abc]  [4]   [10/1/2012]  null
6     [def]  [5]   [12/1/2012]  null
7     [ghi]  [6]   [15/1/2012]  null
8     [abc]  [4]   [17/1/2012]  null
9     [ghi]  [6]   [6/1/2012]   null
10    [abc]  [1]   [13/1/2012]  null
```

Into this:

```
col1  col2   col3  col4         col5
----  -----  ----  -----------  ----
8     [abc]  [4]   [17/1/2012]  2
10    [abc]  [1]   [13/1/2012]  3
6     [def]  [5]   [12/1/2012]  2
7     [ghi]  [6]   [15/1/2012]  3
```

Meaning leave the latest (1) as a representation of every duplicated record.

++ReEditing++

Aaron Bertrand
shawnt00 
e2nburner... and rest of u all
i can't say how much i thank your Reply although i did not yet comprehend that mass of code.
i am now going to check those codes but  not b4 thanking you guys !!

when i first started to program and needed sql querys,  after using

```
Select * From MyTable
```

... my 1'st SQL Statement ...

i said HEY i know SQL !!! .... Now ... look at that deep knowledge of you guys ... THANKS A LOT i know that this post in StackOverFlow will be further useful for other beginners too

Comment: @pst Actually, `COUNT` too in his case

Comment: thanks but it is too complicated for me as i usually do is learn from tutorials , in this case i really need a solution wich will be a c# code behind , that (i guess...) triggers a stored proc...

Comment: i need an SQL CODE example that suits my scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to apply [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and count() to each "slice" of data (meaning grouped by col2 + col3). The count() is used to identify how many rows belong to each such group, and the row_number() is used to apply a "rank" ordered by col4 desc (1 = latest per group, 2 = 2nd latest, etc). This also uses col1 (which looks like a unique column) to break any ties. The CTE can be followed by a query such as a select, update, delete, etc. So you can run the first select to validate that these are the rows you want to keep, and that the counts are correct. If they are, then you can proceed with the updates and deletes. You'll notice that in all cases the row_number() output is used to identify the rows you keep or the rows you discard.

To identify the rows you want to keep:

```
;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 
    c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
      PARTITION BY col2, col3 ORDER BY col4 DESC, col1 DESC
    )
  FROM dbo.table_name
)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, c
  FROM n WHERE rn = 1;
```

Once you've confirmed that those are the row you want to keep, you can update them like this:

```
;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, 
    c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
      PARTITION BY col2, col3 ORDER BY col4 DESC, col1 DESC
    )
  FROM dbo.table_name
)
UPDATE n SET col5 = c
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

Then delete the remainders this way:

```
;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
      PARTITION BY col2, col3 ORDER BY col4 DESC, col1 DESC
    )
  FROM dbo.table_name
)
DELETE n WHERE rn > 1;
```

Or even more simply (assuming col5 was completely null before the update):

```
DELETE dbo.table_name WHERE col5 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Aaron :-)  , do you know any good guide / tutorial for sql server indexes ? –

Comment: @RoyiNamir http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/ also once you've moved on from there Gail's and Grant's blogs are very good: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/category/sql-server/indexes/ http://www.scarydba.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplistic approach. You might find `merge` to be better. These versions preserve the highest col1 value and modify the maxdate column. Aaron's preserves the row with the maxdate. That is a distinction that I doubt is important but should be noted.

```
update MyTable
set col4 = (
    select max(col4)
    from MyTable as m2
    where m2.col2 = MyTable.col2 and m2.col3 = MyTable.col3
),  col5 = (
    select count(*)
    from MyTable as m2
    where m2.col2 = MyTable.col2 and m2.col3 = MyTable.col3
)
where not exists (
    select *
    from MyTable as m2
    where
        m2.col2 = MyTable.col2 and m2.col3 = MyTable.col3
        and m2.col1 > MyTable.col1
        and m2.col4 > MyTable.col4 or m2.col4 = MyTable.col4 and m2.col1 > MyTable.col1
);

delete from MyTable
where exists (
    select *
    from MyTable as m2
    where
        m2.col2 = MyTable.col2 and m2.col3 = MyTable.col3
        and m2.col1 > MyTable.col1
);
```

**EDIT 2** Here's my shot at a `merge` query

```
merge MyTable as target
using (
    select max(col1), col2, col3, max(col4), count(*)
    from Mytable
    group by col2, col3
) as source(id, col2, col3, maxdate, rowcount)
on (
        target.col1 = source.col1
    and target.col2 = target.col2
    and target.col3 = target.col3
)
when matched then
    update set col4 = maxdate, col5 = rowcount
when not matched then delete
```

**EDIT 3** Preserve the row with the original maxdate, breaking ties on col1

```
-- option #1
update MyTable
set col5 = (
    select count(*)
    from MyTable as m2
    where m2.col2 = MyTable.col2 and m2.col3 = MyTable.col3
)
where not exists (
    select *
    from MyTable as m2
    where
        m2.col2 = MyTable.col2 and m2.col3 = MyTable.col3
        and m2.col4 > MyTable.col4 or m2.col4 = MyTable.col4 and m2.col1 > MyTable.col1
);

delete from MyTable
where exists (
    select *
    from MyTable as m2
    where
        m2.col2 = MyTable.col2 and m2.col3 = MyTable.col3
        and m2.col4 > MyTable.col4 or m2.col4 = MyTable.col4 and m2.col1 > MyTable.col1
);

-- option #2
merge MyTable as target
using (
    select max(col1), col2, col3, max(col4), count(*)
    from Mytable
    group by col2, col3
) as source(maxid, col2, col3, maxdate, rowcount)
on (
        target.col2 = target.col2
    and target.col3 = target.col3
    and target.col1 = maxid
    and target.col4 = maxdate
)
when matched then
    update set col5 = rowcount
when not matched then delete
```

Comment: +1, @Jbob Johan also specified col3 as a grouping column so it would be max(col1), col2,col3,max(col4), count(*)... group by col2, col3

Comment: maybe this would do the trick of presenting only the distinct records but i need to delete their clones !

Comment: I think I had already posted an update to my answer. I do wonder though why you need to actually need to delete rows if this is only for a report.

Comment: I think this table was built as the result of a (not normalized) report, not the other way around.

Comment: this is made by a C# applet(EXE) that sends report from computers on wich it's inastalled (via sql queries to the server), to report their condition. stationName is Col2 and ProblemCode is Col3

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY colum2 ORDER BY colum3 desc) RowNum
    FROM    mytable
)
-- deleted rows will be:

delete from mytable
where [yourID] in

(SELECT [yourID]

FROM    a
WHERE   a.RowNum <> 1 )
```

Comment: not trying to think it deeply i can see that you stated [YourID]which stands for a rowid?? (my is ProblemID -- id pk autoincr) cause i need it to be working in a loop on all rec\Rows

Comment: @JbobJohan please stop thinking about this "in a loop." SQL is optimized to perform operations on *entire sets*, not one row (or one set) at a time.

Comment: , Now i can see ROWNum too, is it a row number or i can use this as a variable(or is a parameter) or you ment RowNum to be replaced whith a specific Row Number (i guess its a Variable or acutally a SQL built in variable -constant like)

Comment: @ Aaron Bertrand
i ment go through all records not have to loop ... i would call it raid on the table ... **one big colective sweep** ...  opposed to _specific one_ or few specified ones

Comment: @JbobJohan The "RowNum" is the auto generated by sql code.you do not need to replace it.But you can use it as a variable if you desire.

Comment: @e2burner can u explain?? or did i get it right and by RowNum you did mean for it to work on a specific row say RowNum = 3 then only row 3 will be effected by that script same Question i repeat that i didn't understand what YourID stands For

Comment: @JbobJohan  YourID is the unique id of your record in the table.In your sample it could be "column1".

Comment: ah ok ... just read your reply on RowNum
and last one too now YourID = Column1 for my case

Comment: `tblproblems.problemID` is the `pk int autoincremnetal` so this is my `YourID` in your example so ...

Comment: `WITH a AS ( 
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StationName ORDER BY ProblemCreateDate desc) RowNum 
    FROM    tblProblems
) 
-- deleted rows will be: 
 
delete from tblProblems
where [problemID] in 
 
(SELECT [problemID] 
 
FROM    a 
WHERE   a.RowNum <> 1 ) 
`