# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'rowcount'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this code:

```
merge dbo.tblProblems as target 
using ( 
    select max(problemID), StationName, problemCode, max(ProblemCreateDate), count(*) 
    from dbo.tblProblems 
    group by StationName, problemCode 
) as source(id, StationName, problemCode, maxdate, rowcount) 
on ( 
        target.problemID = source.problemID 
    and target.StationName = target.StationName 
    and target.problemCode = target.problemCode 
) 
when matched then 
    update set ProblemCreateDate = maxdate, probCount = rowcount 
when not matched then delete ;
```

But it yields this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'rowcount'.

And this version of the query:

```
;WITH n AS  
( 
  SELECT problemID, StationName, problemCode, ProblemCreateDate, probCount 
    c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY StationName, problemCode), 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
    ( 
      PARTITION BY StationName, problemCode ORDER BY ProblemCreateDate DESC, problemID DESC 
    ) 
  FROM dbo.tblProblems
) 
 --SELECT problemID, StationName, problemCode, ProblemCreateDate, c 
 -- FROM n WHERE rn = 1; 
UPDATE n SET probCount = c 
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

Yields this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first query, `rowcount` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.100).aspx). Use a different word (e.g. `row_count`) or surround it in square brackets:

```
[rowcount]
```

For the second query, you need a comma after `probCount`:

```
SELECT problemID, StationName, problemCode, ProblemCreateDate, probCount,
------------------------------------------------------------------------^
  c = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY StationName, problemCode),
```

You didn't quite adapt [my code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11927077/61305) correctly (the trailing comma is there).

Comment: `when matched then 
    update set ProblemCreateDate = maxdate, probCount = row_count 
when not matched then delete ;`
**_Msg 10710, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
An action of type 'DELETE' is not allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement._**

Comment: Please don't add code samples as comments. I have no idea what your comment is trying to say, and code is very hard to read this way.

Comment: mybe i should've stick your solution .. Aron this one was short ...i try

Comment: ok ... will do next time .. aron , look at last rows of "when " in code at top of page wich gives an error

Comment: ok aron i did try (see now - reEditing ) Your Code i did , i forgot sorry , and it is clean the select part is working see what i add plz

Comment: and to your question i was wrong .. but the isue is not using less is trying easier the more complex the more hard .. .but i was wrong and your code was first for me tried it (works) .. only update part fails